# How to verify authentication token of multiple type of users for a single route (without code duplication) in Express with JWT?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have an express app where some routes are public(accessible to everyone on the internet) and some are protected. I use JWT for route authentication. I have different type of users in the system, for example: author, subscriber etc. Some of the routes are meant to be access authors and some by subscribers. But there are a few routes which can be accessed by both author and subscribers.

To make sure when a user request to protected routes, I use middleware function for each category of users to verify their authentication token.

An example route accessible to authors only like this bellow,

```
router.get("/", verifyToken.author(), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // doing stuff
    } catch (err) {
        // doing stuff
    }
});
```

An example route accessible to subscribers only like this bellow,

```
router.get("/", verifyToken.subscriber(), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // doing stuff
    } catch (err) {
        // doing stuff
    }
});
```

PS: `verifyToken.author()` or any other middleware function I wrote for the purpose of verifying token are actually closure. Because sometimes I need to pass parameter in the functions. So, an example of these methods will be,

```
module.exposts.author = () => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        const token = req.header("Authorization");
        if (!token) return res.status(401).send({ message: "Access Denied!" });

        try {
            jwt.verify(token, process.env.AUTHOR_SECRET);

            next();
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(401).send({ message: "Access Denied!" });
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
};
```

And when I need to write a function for verifying token for both author and subscriber, I can just check do so and use the method as a middleware to the required route. But I am afraid it is not as simple as it sounds because in reality I don't have just these 2 type of users. And almost all the user types has complex route access where maybe 5 particular type of user can access the route.

As I was saying, let's say author and subscriber is among the 5 user types I said above. So writing a function for author+subscriber and writing another for 5 type of users where author, subscriber exists, it seems so much code duplication.

I hope I am able to explain why I just don't want to write something like this bellow,

```
module.exports.authorSubscriber = () => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        const token = req.header("Authorization");
        if (!token) return res.status(401).send({ message: "Access Denied!" });

        try {
            jwt.verify(token, process.env.AUTHOR_SECRET);

            next();
        } catch (err) {
            try {
                jwt.verify(token, process.env.SUBSCRIBER_SECRET);
    
                next();
            } catch (err) {
                res.status(401).send({ message: "Access Denied!" });
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Instead, I want something like this, where I can re-use the function I wrote for author previously,

```
module.exports.authorSubscriber = () => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        const token = req.header("Authorization");
        if (!token) return res.status(401).send({ message: "Access Denied!" });

        try {
            jwt.verify(token, process.env.AUTHOR_SECRET);

            next();
        } catch (err) {
            exports.author()
        }
    };
};
```

But, `author()` won't work here. It works when called from a route because then it gets the `req, res, next`. But in this case, it is being called from another function and no req, res, next is passed. If I do `exports.author(req, res, next)` in `authorSubscriber` and define author to accept these parameters. it still doesn't work. I think route middleware gets the 'req, res, next` automatically, these things can't be passed manually, can they? This was the reason I made these functions closure because on a similar verifier I need to pass a certain token and middleware doesn't take extra parameters.

I am confused. You may have clearly realized that I have knowledge gaps, that's why I am missing something here.
Please help.

Comment: you have to implement Role-based access control (RBAC) and Attribute-based access control (ABAC) in your node app or if you have already implemented Role-Permission based authentication and authorization then you have to check user's role and permission in the middleware

Comment: Middleware functions are not "special", in that they get their parameters the same way any other functions do. One thing that might be confusing to you is that when you specify a middleware function to express in the route, you give it a reference to the function that it will call later with the (req, res, next) params. i.e., you don't call the middleware function at the point you assign it to the route. You can certainly call the middleware manually yourself, but if you are using the "closure" pattern it might look like `exports.author()(req, res, next)` (note the "extra" parens).

Comment: @Shailendra, I think I am new to these terms, I will read on RBAC, ABAC by searching on google. But if you know any good resource, I would be happy if you refer me to.

Comment: @MykWillis, I didn't know what middleware in  a route is actually an assign. Yes, the code works as expected after applying your suggested changes. In addition to that, can you please suggest me any good read on middleware in Express?

Comment: This seems a good place to start: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are defining the "author" middleware in a closure, as in your examples above:

```
module.exposts.author = () => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        // implementation here
    };
};
```

Then you can indeed re-use it in the "author+subscriber" scenario you've described. But keep in mind that your middleware defined above is NOT a function named `author`; rather, the middleware is an anonymous function that is returned from the function named `author`. So if you want to re-use it in `authorSubscriber`, it would look something like:

```
module.exports.authorSubscriber = () => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        // ...
        try {
            jwt.verify(token, process.env.AUTHOR_SECRET);

            next();
        } catch (err) {
            exports.author()(req, res, next)
        }
    };
};
```

Note that you are calling `exports.author()` first, which will return a reference to the inner function that is the middleware you actually want to invoke.

As other comments have noted, there might be better patterns for this type of access control that you could move toward in the future, but if your goal is simply to re-use the middleware you've already defined in different contexts I think this seems workable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using a great feature of JWT in your solution. You differentiate roles of users based on the key used to sign the token. Instead, you could sign all tokens with one secret (ideally use asymmetrical signing) and in the token include a claim which tells you the type of the user (or types). Then, when you receive tokens, you decode them with the same key, and then just check the claims inside of the token to check the type of the user. No try-catchs required.